# Using BeautifulSoup to select div blocks within HTML

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I am trying to parse several div blocks using Beautiful Soup using some html from a website. However, I cannot work out which function should be used to select these div blocks. I have tried the following:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getData():

    html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.racingpost.com/horses2/results/home.sd?r_date=2013-09-22", timeout=10).read().decode('UTF-8')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    print(soup.title)
    print(soup.find_all('<div class="crBlock ">'))

getData()
```

I want to be able to select everything between `<div class="crBlock ">` and its correct end `</div>`. (Obviously there are other div tags but I want to select the block all the way down to the one that represents the end of this section of html.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct use would be:

```
soup.find_all('div', class_="crBlock ")
```

By default, beautiful soup will return the entire tag, including contents. You can then do whatever you want to it if you store it in a variable. If you are only looking for one div, you can also use `find()` instead. For instance:

```
div = soup.find('div', class_="crBlock ")
print(div.find_all(text='foobar'))
```

Check out the [documentation page](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) for more info on all the filters you can use.