# How to select data within multiple div when no unique id associated with it

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

i am trying to select  "Users Interact, Digital Purchases" for below html in beautifulsoup.but i failed so help me please.

```
  <div class="details-wrapper apps-secondary-color">
    <div class="details-section metadata">
      <div class="details-section-heading">
      <div class="details-section-contents">
          <div class="meta-info">
          <div class="meta-info">
          <div class="meta-info">
          <div class="meta-info">
          <div class="meta-info">
          <div class="meta-info contains-text-link">
          <div class="meta-info">
              <div class="title"> Interactive Elements </div>
              <div class="content">Users Interact, Digital Purchases</div>
          </div>
          <div class="meta-info">
          <div class="meta-info">
          <div class="meta-info contains-text-link">
          <div class="meta-info">
          <div class="meta-info meta-info-wide">
          <div class="details-sharing-section">
          </div>
          <div class="details-section-divider"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I see class = "content " as unique

Comment: check on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011613/using-beautifulsoup-to-select-div-blocks-withing-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on the `class` attribute:

```
soup.find("div", class_="content")
```

Or, with a CSS selector:

```
soup.select_one("div.content")
```

---

If the `content` class is not something uniquely identifying the element and you know the preceding "Interactive Elements" label:

```
import re

label = soup.find("div", class_="title", text=re.compile("Interactive Elements"))
print(label.find_next_sibling("div", class_="content"))
```

Comment: @rashfmnb not exactly, updated the answer with other options.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this in various waysL

```
1. document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML;

2. $('.content').text(); / $('.content').html();

3. soup.find("div", class_="content")

4. soup.select_one("div.content")
```